# IEnumerable<double> convert to IEnumerable<DateTime>

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

Good day!
I have the following block when:

```
var userDateReg = DB.Users.Select(u => u.DateLastVisit - u.DateRegistration).ToArray()
                          .Select(i => i.TotalDays);
return userDateReg;
```

I want to return `IEnumerable<DateTime>` instead of `IEnumerable<double>`

Comment: Subtraction of dates is not a date, it is a `TimeSpan` which you are getting it's days. remove `.Select(i => i.TotalDays)` and you'll get the `TimeSpan`

Comment: ...and `TimeSpan.TotalDays` will be values like 10, 16, 175 - hard to convert to a Date or a TimeSpan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtraction of dates is not a date, it is a TimeSpan which you are getting it's days. remove `.Select(i => i.TotalDays)` and you'll get the TimeSpan:

```
var userDateReg = DB.Users.Select(u => u.DateLastVisit - u.DateRegistration).ToArray();
```

Note that `userDateReg` is an array of `TimeSpan` (duration) which you can access it's days, hours, ....

if you want to get a string that looks like a duration:

```
var userDateReg = DB.Users.Select(u => (u.DateLastVisit - u.DateRegistration).ToString(@"d\.hh\:mm\:ss")).ToArray();
```

now userDateReg will be an array of string that looks like: `3.11:49:25`